# How to test that a Vue directives is called on hover/mouseover?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

I try to test that the`b-tooltip.hover` directive from `bootstrap-vue` is called on hover.
It seems that the directive is called even without triggering the hover event and`buttonWrapper.trigger('mouseover');` doesn't show any effect.

How can I trigger the hover event correctly?

The simplified Vue component `ButtonWithTooltip.vue` which I try to test:

```
<template>
  <b-btn v-b-tooltip.hover="{ title: 'someText'}">Button with Tooltip</b-btn>
</template>
```

The unit test which passes successfully although the line is commented which triggers the hover event:

```
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import ButtonWithTooltip from '@/components/ButtonWithTooltip.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);
localVue.use(ButtonWithTooltip);

describe('ButtonWithTooltip.vue', () => {
  it('shows tooltip on hover over the button', () => {
    const BTooltipDirective = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(ButtonWithTooltip, {
      localVue,
      directives: { 'b-tooltip': BTooltipDirective }
    });

    const buttonWrapper = wrapper.find('button');
    expect(buttonWrapper.exists()).toBe(true);

    // buttonWrapper.trigger('mouseover'); <--- test is passed successfully even without this line

    expect(BTooltipDirective).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(BTooltipDirective.mock.calls[0][1].value).toEqual({
      title: 'someText'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This should be and [already is tested by bootstrap-vue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/0b7de2992b42c094541b574b4bf24bcf10abe22e/src/directives/tooltip/tooltip.spec.js). You should instead focus on testing your own component's behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATED

From comments below:

```
expect(buttonWrapper.attributes('aria-describedby')).toBeDefined()
const adb = buttonWrapper.attributes('aria-describedby')

const tip = document.querySelector(`#${adb}`)
expect(tip).not.toBe(null)
expect(tip.classList.contains('tooltip')).toBe(true)
```

### OLD

Try to test it by checking html content, e.g.:

```
buttonWrapper.trigger('mouseover');
expect(wrapper.contains("someText')).toEqual(true);
```

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/contains.html

Or maybe (not sure):

```
expect(wrapper.find("BTooltip').isVisible()).toEqual(true);
```

Do not forget to remove any mocks, e.g.:

```
directives: { 'b-tooltip': BTooltipDirective }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as the rendered DOM of the tooltip is not part of the wrapper. Instead is appended to the bottom of the page DOM

Comment: what if you check by browser api, e.g. `document.querySelector('.b-tooltip') != null`. i've checked examples in docs and i see that element with class `b-tooltip` will be added when you hover on element.

May be you have to use `attachToDocument` option

Comment: You can take a look to see how BootstrapVue tests the tooltip directive at: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/directives/tooltip/tooltip.spec.js

Comment: @TroyMorehouse thank you, it actually answers my question